# Laravel 5: Send a response first, then process request in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with the Classic Paypal API and I'm stuck on a problem of responding before I process the request data.

```
public function store() {
    // Send an empty HTTP 200 OK response to acknowledge receipt of the notification
    response("", 200);
    // Build the required acknowledgement message out of the notification just received
    // Once it hits this point, nothing is sent to the client.
}
```

I know that in order for the client to receive the HTTP 200 response, I will need to add the return keyword in front of it. However, if I return the response immediately, then the processing of the request will not occur. I looked into before and after middlewares, but unfortunately they are not asynchronous. Is there any way of accomplishing a send then process in Laravel 5?

Comment: what do u meant by asynchronous? this did not work - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#terminable-middleware ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a hack solution to this problem:

```
try {
    return response("", 200);
} finally {
    // Controller logic here
}
```

Comment: The last time I tested this was on Laravel 5.2 so it should work for 5.2, however if you are still using 5.2 I would highly suggest moving to 5.5 since 5.2 is EOL.

Comment: We want to move up, still even with this solution nginx gateway timed out

Comment: The last time I tested this was on Apache 2.4 not on nginx. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: i was trying to skip queue implementation for a while and have some heavy processing done in a controller, so it can answer and then keep processing

Comment: You can probably use Laravel job queue for handling heavy processing outside of a controller. What you can do is have the controller submit a job into the queue and immediately return a successful response when the job is added into the queue. Then in your queue listener perform the processing. That way you aren't limited by PHP's execution time either.

Comment: @jon5477 and future readers note that the function doesn't actually return until the finally block completes.

Answer (score 1):

I found this, looks cleaner

```
response('Response', 200)->send();
// Continue with the script
// Don't forget to exit the script
```