# 'Test webhook error: Timed out' on Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

My web app uses Stripe for payment processing. I have a webhook in Stripe calling mysite.com/callback. When I try to test the webhook, it times out. Orders process successfully through my /charge route and show up in Stripe.

What is wrong with my /callback route? It doesn't update the data in the DB.

**Here is the callback route:**

```
Route::post('/callback', function () {

http_response_code(200);
  $amount=array('1900'=>array('name'=>'small','period'=>"+1 month",'visits'=>1000),
                '7900'=>array('name'=>'medium','period'=>"+3 month",'visits'=>10000),
                '14900'=>array('name'=>'large','period'=>"+6 month",'visits'=>25000),
                '39900'=>array('name'=>'xlarge','period'=>"+12 month",'visits'=>100000),
                '79900'=>array('name'=>'enterprise','period'=>"+24 month",'visits'=>500000),
            );

$input =Input::all();

$email = $input["data"]["object"]["source"]["name"];
$stripe_plan=$amount[$input["data"]["object"]['amount']]['name'];

$user = DB::table('users')
                    ->where('email',$email)
                    ->select('remaining_visits','subscription_ends_at')->first();

$date=$user->subscription_ends_at;
$remaining_visits=$user->remaining_visits+$amount[$input["data"]["object"]['amount']]['visits'];

$affectedRows=User::where('email',$email)->update(['secret' => uniqid(),'stripe_active' => 1,'stripe_plan'=>$stripe_plan,'remaining_visits'=>$remaining_visits,'subscription_ends_at'=> date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date.$amount[$input["data"]["object"]['amount']]['period']))]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Laravel, and it looks like that function doesn't return anything, so Stripe is not getting a response.  I suspect you want to do something like this in there:

```
try {
    return response("", 200);
} finally {
    // All the other fun stuff you're doing after you respond
}
```

*Note: [Partly stolen from this answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764150)*